# Can we render react adaptive cards in bot emulator just like in MS Teams

Tags: reactjs, botframework, bots, emulation, microsoft-teams

What I mean is, can we develop cards on react and render on emulator just like MS teams. I have faced many issues with action handling on developing cards on C#. But I recently find out that we can build cards on react for MS Teams. Is it possible to render the same react adaptive card on bot emulator.

Comment: Your question actually isn't clear (there are multiple questions, it appears). Are you just wanting to know if you can render the card in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on your question (see my comment above), but it sounds like you want to know if you can render the card in the emulator. If you're using Teams, I actually wouldn't bother with the emulator - just interact with the bot directly in Teams. It's easy enough to do, and then you also know 100% what it looks like in Teams.

What might help with *designing* your final card is to use [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) to test this - there's a tab there called "card editor" where you can create card JSON, see a preview, and even send it to yourself.

Out of interest, what issues are you seeing with C# though? I use both C# and JSON, and find them basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking for but may this will help you to render adaptive card using react native.Please take a look at [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-adaptivecards) for adaptive cards in react.
However you can use the App Studio or adaptive card designer to create cards, This sample code will help you in rendering the adaptive card within Teams.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.